# Join View vs. temp table with aggregate function and case when

Tags: oracle, join, case, aggregate-functions, in-subquery

I have a large query with multiple joins including a a subquery (saved as a view). Essentially it looks like this.

```
Select 
 sum(a.amount), 
 case when a.criteria1 = 'c' then 'something' 
  when v.min_rank = 2 then 'something else'
  ....
  else 'other' end
from main_table a
left join view v
 on a.column1 = v.column1
group by
 case when a.criteria1 = 'c' then 'something' 
  when v.min_rank = 'd' then 'something else'
  ....
  else 'other' end
```

Where the view is

```
select min(c.rank) as min_rank, a.column1
from main_table a
left join crieria c
on c.criteria = a.some_column
group by a.column1
```

Oracle

For some reason aggregating causes my subquery (view) to not join (v.columns are null). (If I don't sum and drop the group by v.columns are not null) Replacing the subquery with a temporary table solves the issue, but it's not clear to me as to why. Is their a solution with creating a temporary table, or a probable cause (memory issue?)?

Thanks

Comment: `Replacing the subquery with a temporary table ...` - could you explain it more ? I cannot see any subquery in your queries.

Comment: The subquery is a view. e.g. rather than a typed up subquery I am referencing the view.